# Getting error "No signature of method is applicable for argument types: (com.vproc.market.SubCategory)" in grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to add Category and Sub Categories to Organization(Currently logged in User). I can add category but failed to add subCategories to Organization. When I try, get following message:

```
No signature of method: com.vproc.market.Follower.addToSubCategories() is applicable for argument types: (com.vproc.market.SubCategory) values: [com.vproc.market.SubCategory : 4].
```

I try to add category and subcategories to Organization in follow method of Organization Controller which is below.

**OrganizationController.groovy**

```
   def follow() {
      Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = subscriberService.getLoggedinSubscriber()
      Party organization = loggedinSubscriber?.customer?.party
      def marketInstance = Category.get(params.abc)
      def follower = new Follower()
      follower.followedBy = organization
      follower.category = marketInstance
      def sub = params.list('subcategories')
      sub.each { id ->
      follower.addToSubCategories(SubCategory.get(id))
      }
      follower.save(failOnError: true);
      flash.msg = "Okay. This market is now on your watchlist."
      redirect (action: "profile")
    }
```

In this method I get error in following line:

```
follower.addToSubCategories(SubCategory.get(id))
```

which is mentioned in title of question.

**Organization.groovy**

```
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;
import com.vproc.market.SubCategory;

class Organization extends Party{

    String orgName
    Person contact
    String orgSize
    boolean isVendor  = false

  static hasMany = [follows: SubCategory]

  static constraints = {
    orgName blank: false
    orgSize blank: false
  }
}
```

**Follower.groovy**

```
package com.vproc.market
import com.vproc.member.Organization;

class Follower {

    Category category
    Organization followedBy
  SubCategory subCategory
  static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Follower is domain where Category and subcategories are added to Organization and stored.**

**Category.groovy**

```
package com.vproc.market

import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;

class Category {

    String name
    String description
    static constraints = {
    }
    static hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ]
}
```

**SubCategory.groovy**

```
package com.vproc.market

import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;

class SubCategory {
    String name 

    static hasMany = [requirements: Enquiry]
    static belongsTo = [ category: Category]
    static constraints = {
        requirements nullable:true
    }
}
```

**gsp file**

```
<g:form  controller="organization" params="[temp : marketInstance?.id]" action="follow" method="post">
                <g:hiddenField  name= "abc" value="${marketInstance?.id}"  />
                <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${subcategory?.id}" />
                  <div style="margin-left:200px">
                    <input type="button" class="button-inner" id="check1" value="Check All" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="isChkd" value="true" />
                    <g:each var="subcategory" in="${subCategroyInstanceList}">
                    <div>
                    <g:checkBox class="cb1-element" name="subcategories" value="${subcategory.id}"/>
                    <label for="subcategories"> ${subcategory.name}</label>
                    </div>
                  </g:each>
                  <button class="btn btn-inverse">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </g:form>
```

Summary: I want to add category and subcategories to Organization. I can successfully add category but failed to get subcategories to Organization.

**Error occurs in following lines:**

```
def sub = params.list('subcategories')
      sub.each { id ->
      follower.addToSubCategories(SubCategory.get(id))
      }
```

**No signature of method: com.vproc.market.Follower.addToSubCategories() is applicable for argument types:**

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick look at your domains, the Follower domain has direct association with SubCategory. You can simply assign subCategoty to that no need for `follower.addToSubCategories(SubCategory.get(id))`

Could be something like this:

```
follower.subCategory = SubCategory.get(id)
```

Comment: hi @alidad, it worked but it added only one subcategory though I selected 2 subcategories. Any solution for it.

Comment: Maybe you need to define it as hasMany. Similar to what you have in `Category`

Comment: hi @alidad , you mean that static hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ] should be added to Follower domain, right?

Comment: hi @alidad , I tried with you suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: Based on what you are saying, seems that your requirement requires you to have multiple subcategories for Followers, if that's the case then you need to define a one to many or many to many relationship depending on your model. How you have defined it allows you to have only one subcategory

Comment: hi @alidad, multiple subcategories can be added to Organization at a time. Is this related to association or Array list?

Comment: Alright, take a look at [6.2.1.2 One-to-many](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html). This is your database model. Does not matter when you add your subcategories one at a time or all together. Your model should be designed somehow to handle your requirement.

Comment: hi @alidad, but I already added tatic hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ] to Follower domain, now it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Grails currently and also found similar issue. I am using Grails 2.3.7 and I found this https://github.com/grails/grails-datastore-test-support/issues/1

Even from this link it mentioned it's a bug but I am still not really sure. So far I just do as following and it works for me:

```
if(follower.subCategories == null){
    follower.subCategories = [] 
}
def sub = params.list('subcategories')
  sub.each { id ->
  follower.subCategories.add(SubCategory.get(id))
}
```

please let me know if you have better solution for this problem.. I am also keen to know it.